# Using GL_RGB10_A2UI internal format in glCopyTexImage1D() OpenGL 3.3

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am using GL_RGB10_A2UI internal format in glCopyTexImage1D() API but getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION error. Does OpenGL 3.3 support GL_RGB10_A2UI in glCopyTexImage1D() ?

Comment: If you're using OpenGL 3.x, why aren't you just rendering to that texture to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_RGB10_A2UI` is an [integral image format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format); it contains integers, not normalized floating-point values that are stored as integers. Therefore, unless your *framebuffer* also contains unsigned integer values, this copy operation will fail with the expected error.

Of course, the only way for your framebuffer to have unsigned integers (rather than unsigned normalized integers, which is the usual case) would be to use an FBO. In which case, you could just be rendering directly to this texture, and you wouldn't need to *copy* from it.

I'm guessing you probably meant to use `GL_RGB10_A2`, which represent unsigned *normalized* values.

Comment: I meant to use GL_RGB10_A2UI and not GL_RGB10_A2. So even if I use FBO I won't be calling glCopyTexImage*D() to read the buffer contents. I know this is unnecessary but I am playing around with the APIs. Is there no other way where glCopyTexImage*D() can be called with  GL_RGB10_A2UI ?

Comment: @maverick9888: Does the source you're reading from contain unsigned integers? If not, then no, it won't work.